# Add and Remove class name from image

Tags: jquery

I want to add and remove a class from an image when I click on a list of words. For instance, when I click the word `hello`, I want to add the class `hello`. When I click on `bye`, I want to remove the previous class `hello` and add `bye` to the image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li data-name="hello">Hello</li>
        <li data-name="bye">Bye</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img class="main-image" src="image.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    $('.main-image').addClass(name);
    // I know this doesn't work.
    // $(this).removeClass(name);
});
```

Comment: Check for errors in the console

Comment: I have and there are no errors. Thanks.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps to identify the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another `li` for testing:

Here is a working live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0j4g96tL/50/

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li data-name="hello">Hello</li>
        <li data-name="bye">Bye</li>
        <li data-name="hey">Hey</li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- .links -->

<div class="image">
    <img class="main-image" src="image.png" alt="image">
</div> <!-- .image -->
```

Here is the code:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {

    // Get the class of the clicked list.
    var name = $(this).data('name'),

    // Get that clicked list siblings, In that case the other two lists.
        siblingElements = $(this).siblings();

    //Loop through the siblings.
    for(var i = 0; i < siblingElements.length; i++){

        // Remove the two other siblings classes from the image.
        $('.main-image').removeClass( siblingElements[i]['attributes']['data-name']['value'] );

    } // End loop.

    // Add the clicked list class to the image.
    $('.main-image').addClass(name);

}); // End onclick function.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this is a "li" element. if you would like to modify the image element, you should do so by referencing the name as you did the first.

https://jsfiddle.net/hpmje7ua/17/

**JS**

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        $('.main-image').removeClass(elements[i].getAttribute('data-name'));
    };
    $('.main-image').addClass(name);
});
```

Comment: What if I had a list of 20 names? Would I need to add a `removeClass` for each one?

Comment: No.. is possible iterate for all "li" elements. Fixed Answer

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you should just use jQuery: `$('.main-image').removeClass($('ul li').map(e => $(e).data('name')).join(' '))`

Comment: Thank you to both for the help.